# How to stream a file from node js to angular js

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am new in angular and node js. I am trying to send file contents from node to angular. But i can't read it from my angular code

Here is my code

## Node express

```
var img = fs.readFileSync('./test.jpg');
     //res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpg' });
     //res.end(img, 'binary');
     res.send({'data':img});
     console.log(img);
```

## Angular code is

```
<img ng-src="data:image/JPEG;base64,{{image}}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code,

```
    var img = fs.readFileSync('./test.jpg');

    fs.readFile('./test.jpg', function(err, original_data){

    var base64Image = new Buffer(original_data, 'binary').toString('base64');
    console.log(base64Image);
    res.send(base64Image);
```

Angular js,

```
<img ng-src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{file_name}}" id="photo-id"/>
```